# Simulation of Arduino Mega 2560 with GSM Module using Proteus

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm, simulator

I have really been suffering with my simulation! Tried connecting my arduino mega 2560 to COMPIM (used as GSM Module) in my circuit and also loaded sample code but damn! In vain! I wanted to view the data sent in virtual terminal but am getting nothing! and its also complaining of excessive CPU usage.

This is the circuit as seen below in Proteus.

[image]

And thereafter, the log messages are displayed as shown below.

[image]

Someone please help me out. Am I making a mistake oh? Infact the arduino code for displaying in the simulation is also giving me hard time. The one am using is as shown below.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}
```

Will b every grateful for any help offered.

Comment: Generally speaking, circuit-driven simulation should be used when you have circuit details to work out; connecting two pieces of software is better done on the hardware itself, or by porting at least one piece to run on your PC.

Answer (score 2):

You should download this [GSM Library for Proteus](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2016/03/gsm-library-proteus.html) . You can use this library to simulate your GSM module in Proteus software. You should also check this example where they have discussed Hoe to [Send SMS with GSM module in Proteus ISIS](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2016/04/send-sms-sim900d-proteus-isis.html). I hope it will help you out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had the same problem as you, but I managed to solve it.
Use the TinyGSM library. Open the library folder, locate the Tinygsmcommon file. 
Open the file, line 75 changes the value from Baud 9600 to 2400. That is the minimum speed of my module.

In proteus work with the same speed 2400.
It worked here. Proteus can not handle so much speed.
And do not forget to also change the speed of GSM, place 2400.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that answers need to be in English (see [Quality Standards](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) and [answer]). Please edit your answer to be in English otherwise it will be deleted.

Comment: I have used Google translate. Please edit it if there are any errors in translation.